# JAXB append a xml into a object to be marshaled

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, append

I'd like to append a marshaled object (xml code) into another object to be marshaled.

```
@XmlRootElement
object Child{ 
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement
object Parent{
    @XmlElement
    object Any;
}
```

Marshaling Child:

```
<child xmlns="namespaceOfChild.org">
    <...>
    <...>
<\child>
```

I'd like to set the xml above on Parent.Any to result the code bellow when Parent is marshaled.

```
<parent xmlns="namespaceOfParent.org">
    <any>
        <child xmlns="namespaceOfChild.org">
            <...>
            <...>
        <\child>
    <\any>
<\parent>
```

Note that the namespaces, and other attributes of child, must follow the `child tag` as the code above. I got success when I set the object Child itself on Parent.Any, but the attributes of Child appears like attributes of Parent.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I could save the internal element, `Child`, in a `Document` (org.w3c.dom.Document) and used the function to marshal the `Child` that returned `document.getDocumentElement()` to a `Node` (org.w3c.dom.Node). Then I used this `Node` to set the object in `Parent.Any` and after I can marshal the `Parent`.

Function to marshal Child:

```
private static Node marshal(Object obj) throws JAXBException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.newDocument();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        throw new JAXBException(ex);
    }

    context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.openarchives.oai._2_0.oai_dc");
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.marshal(obj, doc);
    return  doc.getDocumentElement();
}
```

Function to marshal the Parent:

```
private static void marshal(Object obj, OutputStream stream) throws JAXBException {
    context  = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.openarchives.oai._2");
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.marshal(obj, stream);
}
```

When I marshal the Parent, the attributes of Child are inside of `<child>` and the attributes of Parent are inside of `<parent>`.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer, it guided me to the final solution in my environment.

For the one of you, that are trying to do this with JAX-RS and JERSEY JAXB implementation, that are the final steps I had to do.

Let say, we have parent class called metadataType, with a child of XML type "any" and we want to assign a class called Record

This is the "setting" of the object i did when i am creating the object

```
Document doc = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(OAIPMHtype.class,Record.class,RDF.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/ " +
                "http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/ESE-V3.4.xsd");
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.newDocument();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            throw new JAXBException(ex);
        }
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(record, doc);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new JAXBException(e);
    }
        metadataType.setAny(doc.getDocumentElement());
```

And in the class Record I had to add @XMLRootElement , like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "record",namespace = "http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/")
```

Then, if you let Jersey Marshall automatically or not this object it will generate

```
<root xmlns="http://rootschema"><metadata><ese:record xmlns:ese="http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/" schemaLocation="http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/ http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/ese/ESE-V3.4.xsd"> <metadata> </root>
```